# If condition not checking properly in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on submission system. I have a drop down list when user want to edit the section drop-down need to be matched select option to visible in drop down list based on before saved in database value. I write some code for this option but it's not working properly. This same code I have used for the antoher project it's working well. An error also not coming I have checked syntax no problem.

[image]

```
                 <?php  

                    $journalid = $_GET['jiid'];
                    $sqlold = "SELECT `jtype`, `jtitle` FROM `journal` WHERE jid=? LIMIT 1";
                    $db->query($sqlold);
                    $db->bind(1, $journalid);
                    $db->execute();
                    $resjid = $db->resultset();
                    foreach($resjid  as $resjtype){
                          $resjournaltype = $resjtype['jtype'];
                    }                         
                    echo 'Res Ournal Type: '.$resjournaltype;
                    $db->query("SELECT article_name, article_value FROM article_type");
                    $db->execute();
                    $resultrow = $db->resultset();  
                    foreach($resultrow as $vals){
                    if($resjournaltype == $vals['article_value'] ){
                     echo "yes";
                    }

                            ?>
                                    <option <?php //if ( $jtype == $res['article_value'] )  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $res["article_value"];?>"><?php echo $res['article_name']; ?> </option>
                            <?php
                            else {?>
                            <option <?php //if ( $jtype == $res['article_value'] )  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $res["article_value"];?>"><?php echo $res['article_name']; ?> </option>                                  
                            <?php
                                    } 

                                }*/
                                else{   

                            ?>
                            <option <?php //if ( $resjid[0]['jtype'] == $vals['article_value'] )  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $vals["article_value"];?>"><?php echo $vals['article_name']; ?> </option>
                          <?php
                                    }
                                }
                        ?>
```

Comment: `query()` executes the query normally, what driver are you using?

Comment: what does this `$db->execute();` do ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Based on the database you want to select the user select what in previously?

Comment: if( $jtype2 == $res['article_value'] )  not working i have two different db tables compare the values current user what he selected before i want to display that one when he clicked edit button.

Comment: As a tip, try and supply query strings directly to your `query()` call to avoid ambiguity and eliminate mistakes caused by using the wrong variable.

Answer (score -1):

I am searching for a solution every where on the Internet but I forgot some syntax problems. These problems not giving an error. If here I am checking if condition inside for-each loop here is I made a mistake. My actual code is this. The problem was I am checking two string, not numbers. In PHP string values compare with strcmp() function.

```
 if($resjournaltype == $vals['article_value'] )
 {  echo "yes"; }
```

I changed condition like this finally my problem has been solved.

```
if(strcmp($resjournaltype, $vals['article_value']) == true){
    echo $resjournaltype .'-'. $vals['article_value'] ; }
```

Comment: [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns a number.  `<0` if the first string is "smaller" (comes first in the dictionary), `0` if the strings are equal, `>0` if the first string is "bigger" (comes after the second string in the dictionary). You compare this value to `true`; they are equal when `strcmp()` returns a value that is not `0`, i.e. when the two strings are **different**. This is the opposite of the comparison you replaced. There is nothing wrong to compare strings using `==` and if you don't care about their order then `==` is the best way to compare them.

Comment: `$a == $b` is the same as `strcmp($a, $b) == 0`. `strcmp($a, $b) == true` is a longer and slightly slower way to check if `$a != $b`.

Comment: When I mention above code not working. $resjournaltype is string and $vals['article_value'] also string. I want to show selected option on dropdown.

Comment: exact match not working. <option <?php if (strcasecmp($resjournaltype, $vals['article_value']) == 0)  echo 'dataselected'; ?> value="<?php echo $vals["article_value"];?>"><?php echo $vals['article_name']; ?> </option>